# Special connection issues only on one computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

sorry for the sketchy title but I don't know how to describe my problem.

Since 1 month I have connection problem ONLY on one computer:

-longer loading pages (sometimes impossible to load page I need to refresh the page)

-When I m playing I can't load servers list (works very good on other computers in the same network)

I've tried to change canal many times, to change wifi adapter, malwarebytes analysis, check lost packets with wireshark, disable antivirus and firewall, to put my computer near wifi access... and nothing works. Do you know what to do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does you issue also occur when you have a wired LAN connection or only with WiFi?

Comment: I have the problem with Wired LAN and Wifi.

Comment: what OS? what model of computer? (I have had a number of problems with wifi with my Lenovo laptop using Windows 8.1, problems not experienced by others in the same setting)

Comment: Are you sure it is a network problem? Could be something else in the computer that is slowing it up?

Comment: Do you have identical DNS settings? (DNS = nameserver; resolves human-readable URLs like google.com to IP addresses) A bad DNS can cause long delays until a page (and its elements which come from a different site) starts loading.

Comment: It's Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, I've built it (I5 4670K, Z87-C mobo). Maybe a program slowing it, I've search but no result. I have same DNS settings than others computers on my network.